How do I run a .sh file every day at 2:30 AM?
I have a launchd plist located at ~/Library/LaunchAgents designed to run a script located at /Users/admin/Downloads/testing.sh
The script is :
#!/bin/bash

osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "
        cd /Users/admin/Downloads/electronapp || exit
        npm run start
    "
end tell'

How can I configure this to run at 2:30 AM everyday?

See if this helps: Search on "Apple: Timed Jobs Using launchd" I'm suggesting this rather than pasting in the really long URL. The explanation is minimal but I think sufficient. The view of the example is in the raw text of XML, rather than XCode's plist view, but it's the same thing.

What is the plist? What is the error you are running into? Why do you open Terminal in the script instead of just using do shell script?

FWIW, it seems to me that closing this as a duplicate to the selected Q is a bit of a stretch. My rationale: 1.) The other question is almost 8 years old. 2.) All three answers offer a plist run under launchd as the solution... C'mon - we all know there are better answers than that today!!

You can schedule a script by using crontab.
Edit the crontab file with:
crontab -e

Then add the following line:
30 2 * * * /Users/admin/Downloads/testing.sh

You can test your schedule expression with https://crontab.guru.
Read How to run your script on a schedule using crontab on macOS: A step-by-step guide for details.
Note that when you save the crontab file you will have to manually give permissions to your terminal (iTerm2 in my case) to administer your computer and when the cron job is launched you will have to give permissions to cron to control Terminal.app. This can probably also be done from command line.



Can you open Terminal from cron?

Yes, but you may have to give permissions through the System Settings.

How would this work if the crontab entry runs at a time the user is not logged in?

Cron job are run even if user is not logged in. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197615/does-a-job-scheduled-in-crontab-run-even-when-i-log-out

I'm aware of that. But the OP wants to run the code shown in the question which uses AppleScript to open Terminal (the application). Might be worth testing to see whether this works from cron.

Ok, I will try.

@nohillside Tested. It works well.

I wonder if you changed your script to just run npm from cron and skip the AppleScript?

How did you get the permission dialog if you are not logged in?

@bmike You are right. npm can be run directly without AppleScript, I just kept the original script from the OP.

@nohillside You have to be logged in the first time to accept the permissions. Then it's no more necessary as stated in unix stackexchange answer posted in my comment above.
